# ScrollToHorizontalOffset in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I use `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` in windows phone 7? My code doesn't work:

```
imagesScrollview.InvalidateScrollInfo();
imagesScrollview.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(current);
imagesScrollview.UpdateLayout();
```

a working example would be nice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [why my scrollviewer don't work in WP7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688386/why-my-scrollviewer-dont-work-in-wp7)

Comment: please don't repost your questions. see  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: sorry I'm frustrated Just wonder if anyone has work with ScrollToHorizontalOffset in windows phone 7 before :-s

Comment: Can anyone give me a very simple working of ScrollToHorizontalOffset in windows phone 7 please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug in developer tool beta1, I update to beta2 and they all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can help use !

You can use StackPanel for Your project :

After you can write code :

```
<DiaDiemJSC:ItemContain.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </DiaDiemJSC:ItemContain.ItemsPanel>
```

DiaDiemJSC is My control , you can replace it with listview or anything you can add images
Examle:

```
<StackPanel.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </StackPannel.ItemsPanel>
```

here I use the attribute ItemsPanelTemplate to interact with the sort of stackpannel or listviews