# How to make Longlistselector with Horizontal scroll in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

Please help me to make Longlistselector with Horizontal scroll in Windows phone 8.
And I make the longlistselector follow this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LongListSelector doesn't allows you to change scroll orientation. In other controls like the ListBox you can specify the property ItemsPanel to use a StackPanel with horizontal orientation. But that property is not available in LongListSelector (i don't know exactly the reason, but i think it might be something related with the complex grouping, jump list capabilities of the LongListSelector.

If you need to make an horizontal list and you don't need to group your data, you can replace the LongListSelector with a ListBox and use the ItemsPanel property to specify a horizontal stackpanel.

Comment: +1 I would only add some links: http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2011/07/creating-horizontally-scrolling-list.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581380/how-do-i-get-a-horizontal-listbox-to-scroll-horizontally-in-wp7

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I needed to load canvas with different colors in it, I created a long list and rotated it to -90

Comment: Do you have some code that demonstrates how to do this?